# Prove that $f_a(x)$ belongs to $C(X)$ for any $a\in X$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space, and $a\in X$ . Consider the function
$$f_a(x)=d(a,x)$$
Prove that $f_a(x)∈C(X)$ for any $a\in X$ . Here $C(X)$ is the space of continuous functions on $X$ with the distance $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in X}∣f(x)−g (x)∣$.

Please someone explain this.

Comment: You need to show that $f_a(x)=d(a,x)$ is continuous for each fixed $a$. I would try using the triangle inequality for $d$.

Comment: Such distance could be infinite if $X$ is not compact. Consider $X=\Bbb R$ and $f(x)=0$, $g(x)=\text{e}^x$. Usually $C(X)$ we define for $X$ compact. Nevertheless, $f_a$ is always continuous, for any metric space $X$ and any $a\in X$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n \in  X$ such that $x_n \to x \Rightarrow d(x_n,x) \to 0$

Then $|f_a(x_n)-f_a(x)|=|d(a,x_n)-d(a,x)| \leq d(x_n,x) \to 0$

because $$d(a,x_n) \leq d(a,x)+d(x_n,x)$$  $$d(a,x) \leq d(a,x_n)+d(x_n,x)$$

Thus $f_a(x_n) \to f(x)$,so $f$ is continuous.